# Show all rows from a specific date subtract 14 days in a subquery

Tags: sql, select, subquery, sqlplus

I'm using the following query to output data from 3 different tables. Currently it's outputting 800 rows so Im trying to narrow it down:

I want all the rows that have an AgreementDate of 2013-05-05 (this is a random example) minus 14 days of this date.

Trying to do this in my second SELECT but no rows are returning.

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT RA.CustID, RA.AgreementDate, BR.RentalCost, B.BookID, B.Name, 
FROM RentalAgreement RA 
JOIN  BookRented BR
ON (BR.AgreementID = RA.AgreementID)
JOIN Book B
ON(BR.BookID = B.BookID)
WHERE RA.AgreementDate IN (SELECT AgreementDate
                           FROM RentalAgreement
                           WHERE AgreementDate = *SpecificDate - 14Days*);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have a subquery:

```
SELECT RA.CustID, RA.AgreementDate, BR.RentalCost, B.BookID, B.Name, 
FROM RentalAgreement RA JOIN
     BookRented BR
     ON BR.AgreementID = RA.AgreementID JOIN
     Book B
     ON BR.BookID = B.BookID
WHERE RA.AgreementDate = DATE '2013-05-05' - INTERVAL '14' DAY;
```

I am guessing that you are using Oracle based on the sqlplus tag.